# query of time in sql table incorrect due to varied number of digits

Tags: php, mysql, time, calendar, sendmail

I hope you guys have time for an old dog (71 years old) learning new tricks.  I have about a week of experience with PHP and mysql but I am having some fun learning how it works and I have made some progress.  But I have this query/logic/syntax problem and I would like to get some input if you don't laugh too hard at my meanderings.

I have a calendar program that can't put out the reminders the way I want them.  I thought I would take a crack at figuring it out for fun but I can't change the contents of the table lest I trash the whole program.  I was succcessful in making it do what I wanted which was to send all my reminders for a single day in one email by just taking the "time" table entries and sorting them and filtering them into what I wanted.  But a couple of days later, I noticed that any entry that was before 17:00 my time (GMT -7) was fine but any after that time was garbage.  So looking closer at the table, I noticed any time that was after 23:59 GMT was in 5 digits and any before was in 6 digits.  So I found the problem.  I figured all I needed to do was put an IF in the middle and add extra digits accordingly, change it to UNIX epoch time with strtotime and then do date() and only use the hours and minutes.  Are you laughing yet?  Let me reiterate, I know very little about PHP and mysql, but I am learning and that makes me happy and maybe a little younger.

Here's what I've got.  I'll only send the query because hooking up to the db and sending the mail works fine.  This first one works... except for the problem mentioned before...

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$today = date("Ymd");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query = sprintf("SELECT cal_name, cal_time, cal_description, cal_date FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_date = '".$today."'");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$body = '';
$mail = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $mail = sprintf("Event: %s \nTime: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $row[0], date("H:i",((strtotime($row[1])-25200))), $row[2]);
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

This is the crazy fix that is really missing something...

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$today = date("Ymd");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$query = sprintf("SELECT cal_name, cal_time, cal_description, cal_date FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_date = '".$today."'");
$result = mysql_query($query);
$body = '';
$mail = '';
$stt = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $mail = sprintf("Event: %s \nTime: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $row[0], ($stt = { if ($row[1] < 100000, + 1234500000) ELSE ($row[1] + 1234000000) }) date("H:i",((strtotime($stt)-25200))), $row[2])
};
```

I hope one of you wants to take this on and humor an old guy... and stop laughing!

Comment: Are `cal_date` and `cal_time` columns of type `DATE` and `TIME`?

Comment: I believe the answer is no.  cal_date represents the date as 20120301 for instance, and time is represented as a 5 or 6 digit number ie. 01:30 = 13000 and 13:00 = 130000.  If you mean the type in the table they are both int(11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. I added comments for easier understanding:

```
/* I assume that the times and dates in your database are stored in UTC, 
     so set the UTC timezone first. */
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

/* $today might now contain a value of tomorrow if it's past 17:00 in your timezone.
     This is required though, as there could be an event at e.g. 18:00 of your time which would
     not be returned otherwise. sprintf is not needed, as you don't format anyting here */
$today = date("Ymd");
$query = "SELECT cal_name, cal_time, cal_description, cal_date FROM webcal_entry WHERE cal_date = " . $today;

mysql_select_db($dbname);
$result = mysql_query($query);

$body = '';
$mail = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    // Store the value of the returned time in a $fixedTime
    $fixedTime = $row[1];

    /* Simple approach: While the length of the time is less than 6 digits, prepend a leading 0
         This will even work for times like 00:00:15 */
    while (strlen($fixedTime) < 6)
        $fixedTime = '0' . $fixedTime;

    // Now store the unix timestamp (still in UTC!)
    $unixEpoch = strtotime($fixedTime);

    // Set the timezone to your local time ...
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

    // ... and $formattedTime receives the formatted time value in your timezone
    $formattedTime = date("H:i", $unixEpoch);

    // Now create the mail content
$mail .= sprintf("Event: %s \nTime: %s \nDesc: %s \n\n", $row[0], $formattedTime, $row[2]);
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Database columns containing time and date values should be declared as `DATE`, `TIME` or `DATETIME` though.
That would make things alot easier here, as MySQL can handle both timezone conversion and date/time formatting.

Comment: Ha... Works like a dream!  Thank you very much.  The times sets the way I need them but the biggest help is that I picked up a few pointers on how to work with php/sql.  Now I have another big jump to make in this script but I am going to work on it myself for a while and apply some of these principals you taught me.  If I hit a wall, I'll come back but I want to give it my best shot.  *to self -> now how do I give + votes?? *

Comment: @defacto7: I'm glad I could help. You can't give + votes yet (upvotes), because you don't have 15 reputation points earned yet. But you can accept the answer if you want to :-). See [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)